# python strip doesn't work in "for-in"

Tags: python

case1

```
for str in list1:
    str = str.strip()
```

case2

```
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    list1[i] = list1[i].strip()
```

In case1, strip doesn't work.

In case2, strip works.

What's the difference between 1 and 2?

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to use built-in type names like `str` as variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str = str.strip()` is a reassignment of the local loop variable `str`. Any string objects referenced by the list will remain unchanged. Strings are immutable in Python. If you want string variables to reference different strings you have to reassign them!

Your first loop is roughly equivalent to:

```
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    s = list1[i]  # do not shadow the built-in str
    s = s.strip()
```

Which should make it even clearer why the list is unimpressed.

Comment: and _don't use `str` as a variable name_

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Added a note.

Comment: Thanks. I got it!

Answer (score 0):

you can't us python default keywords as variable names